# A control variable that forms part of the definition of the dependent variable: Drop it or transform it?

Tags: model, predictor

My aim is to analyze, using OLS, how Y (firms' benefits) depend on some factors. To normalize Y, I divide it by firms' size (S). Therefefore, my dependent variable is Y/S. To know how size affect benefits, I would like to include S itself in the set of control variables. A standard solution that I have seen in many papers is to use log(S) instead of S, so that the coefficient of S can also be interpreted as a semielasticity.

A previous [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57780/using-the-dependent-variable-as-part-of-a-control-variable) deals with this problem, but the answers, at least for me, were not quite clear.

My question is what is the best solution to this problem? Does using S cause any problem? Is it better to use a transformation of S, e.g. log(S)? Is it better not use S at all?

Thanks in advance.